# How to implement lwIP+SNMP in LPCxpresso?

Tags: snmp

I am using lpcxpresso software and done with lpcopen's webserver example . Now I would like to implement SNMP with the existing lwip present in webserver. I have seen the steps to build SNMP agent on some websites and even tried to implement them but i am getting the errors. Please help me out.

I am following this website for building SNMP agent

https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_0_x/group__snmp.html

Errors :

1) In function 'main':
../example/src/webserver.c:173:34: error: 'snmp_ifType_ethernet_csmacd' undeclared (first use in this function)

2) make: *** [example/src/webserver.o] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able find the solution. I didn't set the paths properly that's why I was getting above error. For setting the path or include files , Right Click on the project--->Properties----->C/C++ Build----->Settings--->MCU C compiler---->includes
[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBSNa.png)

It works!